# Control is set to visible false, jQuery selector fails

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-2.0

Hi I have some controls on an asp.net modal which I show manually via code behind. Now I am trying to attach a selector on one of the controls inside `pageLoad()`, problem being is that the modal container is initially set to visible=false.

I tried checking for length but it still throws exception

```
if ($('#<%= myControl.ClientId %>').length > 0)
{
    $('#<%= myControl.ClientID %>').click(function() {
        // Do work
    });
}
```

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'myControl' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things here, the first/main issue is that `myControl` isn't defined in the current scope, wherever you are in ASP.Net, that's *entirely* a .Net side problem.

For the Script, there are more issues, `.ClientID`, not `.ClientId`.  Also, there's no need to check for it's existence, you can just do:

```
$('#<%=myControl.ClientID%>').click(function(){
  // Do work
});
```

...if the control isn't there, it just won't find/bind anything.  There's also an easier way to go about it in ASP.Net, if there's a unique class you can give it, just give add that class, e.g. `CssClass="MyClass"`, then use *that* as your selector; like this:

```
$('.MyClass').click(function(){
  // Do work
});
```

This allows you to put the script in an external file instead of the page as well, another benefit to the user.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, do you know a way how to to set the element invisible while making it available for jquery selector's at the same time ?

Comment: @Damien - For those cases you need to give it a `display: none;` style, if you want it actually rendered in the page.  You could create a hidden class, for example `.hidden { display: none; }` then use that in combination with the class approach I showed above: `CssClass="MyClass hidden"`, very clean :)

Comment: @Damien Joe, in the code behind when you set something to visible=false it simply doesn't send it to the browser. What you need is to set the css property to style="display:none;"

Comment: Thanks for the tips Nick, they helped me a lot.